# $concatArrays with $map ignores $concatArrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having a problem understanding why the following is producing illogical results.
We know that `$concatArrays` takes in an array of arrays, and returns the content of each in one single array.
We know that `$map` takes in an array and transforms the elements to something else which result in a new array modified to one function.

My problem occurs when combining `$concatArrays` of a `$map`. Take this for example:

```
db.product.aggregate([
        {$replaceRoot: 
            {newRoot: {
                "_id":       "$_id",
                "availablesizes": 
                    {$concatArrays: {$map: {
                        "input": [[1],[2],[3]],
                        "in":    "$$this",
                    }},
            },
        },
    }},
]);
```

For the sake of testing, I replaced the variable array "input" with a static one of similar structure.

Evaluating logically ... `$map` stage is going to return `[[1],[2],[3]]` literally, since each element is returned as is. Then `$concatArrays` should return `[1, 2, 3]` as it flattens the array.
**BUT** the actual result is `[[1],[2],[3]]` !!

**If I remove `$concatArrays`, the result stays the same**:

```
db.product.aggregate([
        {$replaceRoot: 
            {newRoot: {
                "_id":       "$_id",
                "availablesizes": 
                {$map: {
                        "input": [[1],[2],[3]],
                        "in":    "$$this",
                },
            },
        },
    }},
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in MongoDB (as of version 4.0 at least). Due to the design of the expression language.

Check https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31786.

David Storch says:

> For any such n-ary expression, which I will call $nary, the syntax
>   {$nary: "$myArg"} is simply a shorthand for {$nary: ["$myArg"]}. These
>   two expression are identical in meaning.